# Thumnails and Image Numbers

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using FancyBox to display a large number of pages that make up a book .. I use Fancybox because it seems to be the only gallery pluggin out of the myriads i have tried which handles images bigger than the screen in a sensible way.

I am using the thumbnails as i want to be able to jump through the images, say from image 1 to image 30, without going through each image, but the thumbnails all look the same - is there any way of being able to customorise the thumbnail to just show an image number.  Also because the images are very large is there a way of giving it a different url to use for the thumbnail than the full size image?

Thanks you in advance for any help

Comment: are you talking about fancybox v2.x with `thummbs` option?

Comment: yes , sorry if not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had that request before but unfortunately there is not a way to do it "out-of-the-box", you have to do it manually.

Considering that you are using the latest version of fancybox (**v2.0.5**), follow these steps:

1: make a copy of the file `jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js` (`helpers` folder) and rename it with something like `jquery.fancybox-thumbs-NO-image.js`. We will modify this file while keeping the original.

2: edit the new file (`jquery.fancybox-thumbs-NO-image.js`) and look for the line **49**, where it says:

```
list += '<li><a style="width:' + thumbWidth + 'px;height:' + thumbHeight + 'px;" href="javascript:jQuery.fancybox.jumpto(' + n + ');"></a></li>';
```

and replace that line with this:

```
list += '<li><a style="width:' + thumbWidth + 'px;height:' + thumbHeight + 'px;" href="javascript:jQuery.fancybox.jumpto(' + n + ');">' + (n+1) + '</a></li>';
```

3: look for the line **55** where it says

```
//Load each thumbnail
$.each(F.group, function (i) { ...
```

and comment out the whole `$.each()` function using the [javascript multi-line comments syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comments.asp) (like:  `/* $.each ... */` ) all the way through the line **94** +/-

save and close your file.

4: link to that file in your html document like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox2.0.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs-NO-image.js"></script>
```

instead of the original file.

5: To add some style to your numbers add an inline CSS declaration (after you loaded all the fancybox css files) like:

```
<style type="text/css">
 #fancybox-thumbs ul li a {
  border: 0 none !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
</style>
```

6: The javascript. You may use your preferred API options. Just notice the `thumbs` option, where I set values that match better the numbers' size (the `height` is the same as the `line-height` in my CSS inline declaration for instance)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.fancybox').fancybox({
  prevEffect : 'fade',
  nextEffect : 'fade',
  afterLoad : function() {
   this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
  },
  helpers: {
   title: {
    type: 'inside'
   },
   thumbs: {
    width   : 16,
    height  : 16
   }
  }
 }); // fancybox
}); // ready
</script>
```

And voila!. [See DEMO](http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/numbersInsteadofThumbs_27feb12.html)

**NOTES for Fancybox v2.0.6 (May 30, 2012)**:

- The step No. 2 above points to the line 49 : For fancybox v2.0.6 should be line 55.
- The step No 3 points to the line 55 : For v2.0.6 should be line 62 all the way through the line 100+/-.

Subsequent versions may move the line numbers again but basically you should look for the same chunks of information.

Remember that we are editing our own customized version of the `jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js` file.

Comment: Thanks!  That demo is absolutely perfect.  Id come up with a hack by switching to using 'inline' mode rather than images, and in this case it allows you to have a different thumnail (that was unexpected) so I had used some code to write out the number as a picture.  Using 'inline' method to display images solved another problem in that it doesnt seem to preload images on a normal gallery which is a bit of a nuisance when you have large ones .. also it doesnt handle the overflow of the image quite so well, but cant complain.  Thanks very much for that!